# How to configure the slow query log in TiDB?

Tags: distributed-database, tidb

I have already set the `slow_query_log` to `OFF`, but why the `tidb_slow_query.log` still log the queries with execution time of several hundred milliseconds?

[slow query log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1DTj.png)

Answer (score 0):

In TiDB, the `slow_query_log` logs queries with execution time greater than 300 milliseconds by default. You can modify this value in the TiDB configuration file according to your need.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F61oJ.jpg)